# Using printf with escape sequences?

Tags: terminal, escape-characters, printf

I can change my cursor shape like this:

```
printf "\x1b[\x31 q" # block :)
printf "\x1b[\x35 q" # ibeam :)
```

But when I assign that to a variable with `%s` and expand using `printf`, it doesn't work:

```
CURSOR="\x1b[\x3%s q"

printf ${CURSOR} 1 # block :(
printf ${CURSOR} 5 # ibeam :(
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766) or any of the questions linked to [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346). In short, **quote your variables!**.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, Where am I missing double quotes here?! It would have been awesome if this is fixed with a double quotes; Or do you mean *quote* in some general sense?

Comment: Please read those Q&As

Comment: In the second set of commands, the arguments `printf` sees are `\x1b[\x3%s`, `q` and `1` (or `5`). Since `printf` reuses format strings until the arguments are exhausted, the format string is printed twice, once with `q` replacing `%s` and once with `1` (or `5`). You should quote your variables there; otherwise it has a completely different meaning.

Comment: Do you know that `printf` does not support hex backslash escapes? Your code is not portable as it relies on non-POSIX features.

Comment: Thanks @schily. I will look into that. Currently I am using this only on `zsh`/`archlinux`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\x31` is the character `1` and `\x35` is `5`, so in this case you don't have to use escape sequences.

```
CURSOR="\x1b[%s q"

printf "${CURSOR}" 1
printf "${CURSOR}" 5
```

Comment: I thought I knew a little bit of `escaping`, now I understand that it is an ocean :-).

Answer (score 3):

By using `\x3%s`, only `\x3` is interpreted as an escape sequence, the `%s` is no longer part of it. If you want to make that part an argument, you'll have to use `%b` and bring out the whole `\x31` to have that interpreted as an escape sequence:

```
$ printf "\x1b[\x31 q" | od -c
0000000 033   [   1       q
0000005
$ printf "\x1b[%b q" "\x31" | od -c
0000000 033   [   1       q
0000005
```

Comment: Thanks for showing how to use debugging tools like`od`. I was struggling to print these characters on the screen :-)